# text in text editors gets scrambled after defining set_prompt

Tags: bash, prompt

I've set `set_prompt` to print prompt always on a new line.

```
set_prompt() {
   local curpos
   stty -echo
   while read -t 0; do :; done
   echo -en "\033[6n"
   IFS=';' read -s -d R -a curpos
   stty echo
   (( curpos[1] > 1 )) && printf "\n"
}
```

but now, if I edit a file in text editors like `emacs` or `nano`, the text gets scrambled like printing character at wrong place or cursor jumps ahead or back while navigating, making text overlap.

---

at this point

```
PS1=\[\]$(git rev-parse --git-dir > /dev/null 2>&1 && git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null || echo ${HOSTNAME})\[\]:\[\]\W\[\] Necktwi\[\]$\[\]
PROMPT_COMMAND=set_prompt
```

---

Instead of setting the `set_prompt`, one can also do

```
PS1='$(printf "%$((COLUMNS-1))s\r")'$PS1
```

but even this gives the glitch in `emacs`, not tested `nano`, but not as bad as the above. I was able to correct this much less scrambled text by deleting the generated spurious characters.

Comment: What is the value of your `$PS1` and `$PROMPT_COMMAND` variables?

Comment: updated the question about them

Comment: The purpose of the `\[` and `\]` are to contain *non-printing* characters. If there is nothing in between them, they are useless, so you can tidy up your PS1. You need to add them to the set_prompt funtion: `echo -en "\[\033[6n\]"`

Comment: I am curious about the purpose of that function. Why do you have it?

Comment: actually, there is a color code between `\[\]`. `echo -en "\[\033[6n\]"` is printing `\[\]` before the prompt.

Comment: Can you include the output of `echo $PS1 | xxd` or something equivalent, so we can see those control characters?

Comment: @glennjackman: I'm pretty sure you're wrong about needing `\[` and `\]` in the `set_prompt` function. Those codes only have [a special meaning](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/bash-prompt-escape-sequences.html) in `PS1` and `PS2`. The OP's `set_prompt` function is just normal bash code, and using them there will just cause them to be printed verbatim before each prompt. Anyway, the OP's code works for me as written, printing an extra newline before the prompt if the cursor is not at the start of the line.

Comment: `PS1='$(printf "%$((COLUMNS-1))s\r")'$PS1` is working good though.

Comment: `PS1='$(printf "%$((COLUMNS-1))s\r")'$PS1` is also giving the glitch but not as bad as the other one!